# Java Comparable Type

Tags: java, object, types, comparator

Does anyone have a link for the java `Comparable<T>` type? 
I can only find documentation concerning the interface. I require
information concerning Objects of type `Comparable`, not objects that
implement the `Comparable` interface.

For example:

```
Comparable element = "6";
```

Eclipse allows that expression, although it gives a warning that 
it must be parameterized, (i.e. `Comparator<T>`). Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparable is an interface, not a class. You can assign the String "6" to a Comparable variable because String implements `Comparable<String>`.

Specifying the type parameter will get rid of the warning :

```
Comparable<String> element = "6";
```